# How to interchange/reorder rows in gridview containing input entries

Tags: c#

[image: Gridview with input entries]

In the attached image, the gridview has several columns with specific user needed rows. I just need to reorder the rows in the manner of

```
Rowindex   SOLID/YARN        Rowindex   SOLID/YARN       
  0           AOP               0           AOP
  1           Solid       =>    1           AOP
  2           AOP               2           Solid
```

Interchange the row and rowindex using the columns size range, Description and Solid/Yarn.
Is that possible???

Comment: You could do this, but you have had to disable all sorting features for columns. Otherwise it would be pointless.

Comment: I am not using any sorting techniques for columns. Kindly share me the coding snippet for reference??

Answer (score 0):

This code swaps rows:

```
class DgvTools
{
  public static void MoveRow(DataGridView dgv, int dgvRowIndex0, int dgvRowIndex1)
  {
    if (dgv.Rows != null)
       if (dgv.DataSource != null)
       {
                DataTable dt = null;
                if (dgv.DataSource is BindingSource)
                {
                    dt = (DataTable)((BindingSource)dgv.DataSource).DataSource;
                }else if (dgv.DataSource is DataTable)
                {
                    dt = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
                }

                DataRow row0 = ((DataRowView)dgv.Rows[dgvRowIndex0].DataBoundItem).Row;
                int row0Index =  dt.Rows.IndexOf(row0);

                DataRow row1 = ((DataRowView)dgv.Rows[dgvRowIndex1].DataBoundItem).Row;
                int row1Index =  dt.Rows.IndexOf(row1);

                MoveRow(dt, row0Index, row1Index);
      }
   }


   public static void MoveRow(DataTable dt, int row0Index, int row1Index)
   {
        if (dt != null)
        {
            int lowIndex = Math.Min(row0Index, row1Index);

            int highIndex = Math.Max(row0Index, row1Index);

            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 2)
                if (lowIndex != highIndex)
                    if ((lowIndex >= 0) && (highIndex < dt.Rows.Count))
                    {
                        DataRow oldRow = dt.NewRow();
                        oldRow.ItemArray = dt.Rows[lowIndex].ItemArray;

                        dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[lowIndex]);
                        dt.Rows.InsertAt(oldRow, highIndex);
                    }
        }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
 DgvTools.MoveRow(dgvDisabled, 1, 2);
```